# Why the length of a curve involves derivatives

Tags: vector-analysis, curves, arc-length

Suppose we have a parametrised curve with position $A$ at $\underline{r}(t_0)$ and position $B$ at $\underline{r}(t_1)$ given by $$\underline{r}(t) = x(t)\underline{i}+y(y)\underline{j}+z(t)\underline{k}$$ In all the textbooks I could find, they give out the formula giving the length of the curve, but in none of them it is explained why that's the correct formula. Here it is $$L = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}|\dot{\underline{r}}(t)|dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\sqrt{\dot{\underline{x}}(t)^2+\dot{\underline{y}}(t)^2+\dot{\underline{z}}(t)^2}dt$$ 
Can someone please explain to me in a detailed way, why this is true? I understand why $|\dot{\underline{r}}(t)| = \sqrt{\dot{\underline{x}}(t)^2+\dot{\underline{y}}(t)^2+\dot{\underline{z}}(t)^2}$ but not why we put this (and not the position vector or something else) under the integral. Why are we summing up the speeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always for intiution, its a good idea to think of approximations to the integral. Choose, given $\eta >0 $ points $t_0 = \tau_0 < \ldots < \tau_n = t_1$ with $\tau_{i+1}-\tau_i < \eta$ for each $i$. Then the length of the curve we want to calculate is approximated by the length of the curve consisting of the segments from $r(\tau_i)$ to $r(\tau_{i+1})$. The length of this segment is
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|} \abs{r(\tau_{i+1}) - r(\tau_i)} = \abs{r'(\theta_i)}\cdot (\tau_{i+1} - \tau_i) $$
for some $\theta_i \in(\tau_i, \tau_{i+1})$ by the mean value theorem. Hence the length is approximated by 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \abs{r'(\theta_i)} (\tau_{i+1} -\tau_i) $$
This is a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \abs{r'(\tau)}\,d\tau$, hence for $\eta \to 0$ this converges to 
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \abs{r'(\tau)}\, d\tau. $$

Comment: @Thank you! This might sound silly as I'm not remembering the Riemann Sum correctly maybe, but at the second step, why is it still a Riemann Sum if $|r'(\theta_i)|$ is not the supremum (so this is not the upper darboux sum) nor the infimum (so this is not the lower darboux sum) of the interval $(\tau_{i+1}-\tau_i)$ ? If you could please expand more on that it would be great! I studied Riemann Sums as limits of the UDS and LDS, but here $|r'(\theta_i)|$ does not seem in the interval either. I mean surely by MVT $\theta_i$ is in the interval, but how do I know that $|r'(\theta_i)|$ is?

Comment: *A* Riemann sum, not the upper or lower Darboux sum, for a function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ with respect to $a=\tau_0 < \ldots < \tau_n = b$ is given by the sum 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(\theta_i)(\tau_{i+1}-\tau_i) $$
where $\theta_i \in[\tau_i, \tau_{i+1}]$ are any points. The sum above is a Riemann sum for the function $|r'|$. I do not know in what sense you want to have it "in the interval"?

Comment: Oh okay, now it makes sense, I was confused: I thought that we also had to have $f(\theta_i)\in [\tau_{i+1},\tau_i]$ but that is not true. However looking here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral I saw that the UDS and LDS are equivalent to the Riemann Integral for continuous functions, so now it makes sense!

Comment: The mean value theorem cannot be applied, since the dimension is greater than $1$. E.g. the unit circle has $|r(2\pi)-r(0)|=0$ but for any $\theta$ we have $|r'(\theta)|=1\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

SKETCH OF PROOF: It is an application of  sums. Consider a parametrised curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $t \in [t_1,t_2]. $ then you take a partition of $[t_1,t_2]$ . Then break your curve to straight parts. That is, take a partition of your curve. Then the length of this curve is the sum of the length of those straight parts. Use the mean value theorem and you get the result for a curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ . Generalize this for higher dimensions.

Comment: same question as below: shouldn't we find the Upper Darboux sum and the lower darboux sums, take their limits and check if they are equal? How come this method works even if we don't find either (nor PDS or LDB)?

Comment: Check this wiki link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length . As you can see these are not Darboux sums but you sum the length of those straight parts. No need for supremum here.

Comment: it makes sense thank you!

Comment: I am glad that I helped you 